# Return Firebase Document Count as Table Row Count

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a function that gets the count of firestore documents in a collection and I want to use this count as the return for the table view function numberOfRowsInSection. The return is called before the count is retrieved from the server and crashes the program. I believe I need to use closures to make the return wait for the completion, but I am not sure how to return an Integer from a closure. I am quite new to swift and even newer to Closures.

```
func getCount(completion: @escaping (Int) -> (Int)) {
    let today = getToday()
    let eventsRef = db.collection("users").document("test@test.com").collection(today)
     eventsRef.getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in

            if let err = err {
                print("Error getting documents: \(err)")

            } else {
                completion((querySnapshot?.count)!)
            }

    }

    }

 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {


        getCount { (count) in

            self.count = count
        }

        return count!

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set an instance array

```
var arr = [<#typeHere#>]()
```

//

return it's count here

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
   return arr.count
}
```

and reload the table here

```
func getCount(completion: @escaping (Int) -> (Int)) {
  let today = getToday()
  let eventsRef = db.collection("users").document("test@test.com").collection(today)
  eventsRef.getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
        }  
         // fill the array here  
         tableView.reloadData() // if it's a background thread embed code in DispatchQueue.main.async {---}
    }
}
```

Comment: Where can I call the getCount function? I called it from the numberofrows function and this ended with an infinite loop where it was constantly reloading the table...which is obvious to me now.

Comment: you need to call it inside **viewDidLoad**

Comment: I have my tableview delegate and datasource in a separate class file. Can I pass an integer from view controller to this separate class file?

Comment: declare a var inside that class ans when you create object assign value to this var , also you can use delegate pattern

Comment: I am not sure I follow your logic...Could you show me a short snippet? Sorry to take so much of your time!